# Remove rows with duplicated values for one column but only when the latest row has a certain value for another column

Tags: r, duplicates

Consider the following data frame

```
address <- c('9A Eagle Point N','9A Eagle Point N','9A Eagle Point N', '9999 Mineral Wells Highway', '9999 Mineral Wells Highway')
sale_status <- c('Succeeded', 'Failed', 'Failed', 'Failed', 'Failed')
sale_date <- as.Date(c('2020-03-01','2020-02-01', '2020-01-14', '2020-03-02', '2019-08-01'))
df = data.frame(address, sale_status, sale_date)
```

such that the data looks like this:

```
1           9A Eagle Point N   Succeeded 2020-03-01
2           9A Eagle Point N      Failed 2020-02-01
3           9A Eagle Point N      Failed 2020-01-14
4 9999 Mineral Wells Highway      Failed 2020-03-02
5 9999 Mineral Wells Highway      Failed 2019-08-01
```

I am trying to write code such that for any number of n rows with matching addresses, that the earlier matching (duplicated) rows are removed whenever the latest row was successfully sold within 180 days of the second-to-most-recent sale's date. I only want the previous matching rows to be removed when the latest rows have a `sale_status` of "Succeeded (`df$sale_status == "Succeeded`) and the earlier matching rows have a `sale_status` of "Failed" (`df$sale_status == "Failed"`)

I know this sounds incredibly convoluted, but any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I checked out several other posted questions but none seemed to address this use case.

I believe the resulting data frame would look like this:

```
1           9A Eagle Point N   Succeeded 2020-03-01
4 9999 Mineral Wells Highway      Failed 2020-03-02
5 9999 Mineral Wells Highway      Failed 2019-08-01
```

Comment: Do you mean remove everything after "Succeeded" ? Can you also include in the example a case for `rows are removed whenever the latest row was successfully sold within 180 days of the second-to-most-recent sale's date` ?

Comment: For every row with matching addresses, I’m trying to remove the duplicated rows only when the most recent row has a sale status of “Succeeded” essentially If a property successfully sold, I want to remove the failed attempts before.

Comment: You want to remove `Failed` rows, but leave `Failed` rows in if they happened more than 180 days prior to the `Succeeded` date? If this is your intended logic, none of the dates in your example test this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with `lag` from `dplyr`.

First we calculate the difference in days between dates per address with `lag`. We then calculate the cumulative days into the past from the final succeeded date with `cumsum`. Then we filter rows that fulfill any of the following:

1. Succeeded
2. Never sold
3. Failed more than 180 days before the sale succeeded

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(desc(sale_date)) %>%
  group_by(address) %>% 
  mutate(elapsed = sale_date - lag(sale_date,1L,default=first(sale_date)),
         cumelapse = cumsum(as.integer(elapsed)),
         sold = any(sale_status == "Succeeded")) %>%
  filter( sale_status == "Succeeded" | sold == FALSE | (sold == TRUE & cumelapse < -180)) %>%
  ungroup %>% arrange(address,sale_date)
#  address                    sale_status sale_date  elapsed   cumelapse sold 
#  <fct>                      <fct>       <date>     <drtn>        <int> <lgl>
#1 9999 Mineral Wells Highway Failed      2019-08-01 -214 days      -214 FALSE
#2 9999 Mineral Wells Highway Failed      2020-03-02    0 days         0 FALSE
#3 9A Eagle Point N           Succeeded   2020-03-01    0 days         0 TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

We can check if `any` `sale_status == 'Succeeded'` in each `address` and select only rows which are greater than the corresponding `sale_date`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(address) %>%
  filter(if(any(sale_status == 'Succeeded')) 
        sale_date >= sale_date[which.max(sale_status == 'Succeeded')] else TRUE)

#  address                    sale_status sale_date 
#  <fct>                      <fct>       <date>    
#1 9A Eagle Point N           Succeeded   2020-03-01
#2 9999 Mineral Wells Highway Failed      2020-03-02
#3 9999 Mineral Wells Highway Failed      2019-08-01
```